# C# UWP RichTextBox change font size

Tags: c#, uwp

UWP: how to change font size (and eventually other font properties) of selection in RichTextBox?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself: just work on Document's Selection's CharacterFormat, like here:

```
 Windows.UI.Text.ITextSelection selectedText = myRichTextBox.Document.Selection;
 if (selectedText != null)
 {
     Windows.UI.Text.ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
     charFormatting.Size = 18; //Or whatever
     selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite you already answered yourself, I would like to point out that the title might lead to confusion.

The **RichTextBox** control is used for **read-only text**, in other words, to display content, like the more simple **TextBlock** control. User input is not possible and the content for this control must be set on code, either using XAML and/or C#. 
Therefore, the control you should use is a **RichEditBox**, for which your answer is valid.